# How to snap and trace contour lines from 'opentopomap' xyz layer?

Tags: xyz, trace, opentopomap

I've created a project and i'm using the xyz 'opentopomap' as my base.

I would like create my own layers by tracing over the contour lines provided by opentopomap.

I have downloaded the raster tracer plugin but when I try to use it, I just get a python error.

Is raster tracer plugin the correct solution or is there a better way to solve this ?

Comment: opentopomap seem to use SRTM data for elevation, it could be easier to download existing contour lines (from here for exemple https://www.opendem.info/index.html) or to recreate the contour lines from SRTM data (if you need more control)